# Sqlalchemy specify table size during create_all call

Tags: python, oracle, sqlalchemy

Is there any way to specify the size for the tables in Oracle database when I use `schema.create_all()`?

Generally speaking, I am looking for ways to increase Oracle table space size from python and I am specifically using sqlalchemy to work with the database. I know I can use Oracle's SQL command (like ALTER) to alter the size of the tables in Oracle database. But can I do something similar from sqlalchemy?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17120/dfiles003.htm

Comment: One question is why you want to do that? Oracle expands the table size as it needs.

Comment: It needs to be initialized with autoexpand for that, and that's what I want to accomplish with the alter command.